# How to speed up query for datetime in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

```
SELECT *
FROM LOGS
WHERE datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

I have a big table LOGS (InnoDB). When I try to get last month's data, the query waits too long.

I created an index for column datetime but it seems not helping. How to speed up this query?

Comment: Do you need all fields returned? If not, selecting  only the required fields will speed up the query

Comment: Try declaring a variable for the date you and put that in the where clause instead of doing toe calculation.  It can speed it up, maybe not a huge amount but some.   Plus if your not using every field in the table do not select *

Comment: Appreciate your help but I need all columns.

Comment: Have you checked the plan? Does it use your index?

Comment: @Brad - The evaluation of a constant expression, like that one, is done only once anyway.  Furthermore, the cost of that calculation is tiny compared to the fetching of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the database records are inserted in oldest to newest, you could create 2 calls. The first call requesting the ID of the oldest record:

```
int oldestRecordID = SELECT TOP 1 MIN(id) 
FROM LOGS 
WHERE datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Then with that ID just request all records where ID > oldestRecordID:

```
SELECT *
FROM LOGS
WHERE ID > oldestRecordID
```

It's multiple calls, but it could be faster however I am sure you could combine those 2 calls too.

Comment: Your idea is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the only thing you can do is create a clustered index on `datetime`.  This will ensure that the values are co-located.

However, I don't think this will solve your real problem.  Why are you bringing back *all* records from a month.  This is a lot of data.

In all likelihood, you could summarize the data *in the database* and only bring back the *information* you need rather than all the *data*.